# Is there a way to join S3 buckets and prefixes?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm simply trying to join a bucket `s3://somebucket` with a key `foo/bar` using something similar to a `os.path.join` but for S3. I tried using `urllib.parse.urljoin` but it doesn't seem to support the protocol?

```
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('s3://somebucket', 'foo/bar')
'foo/bar'
```

Is there some other way to manipulate this using `urllib`?

Comment: They are just strings, so use `+`, like this: `'s3://somebucket/' + 'foo/bar'`

Comment: `os.path.join` works fine too.